# Table in Visual Basic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have code table in vbhtml:

```
For Each item In Model
    @<tr>
        <td>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "EditUser", item.A2UserID)">@Html.DisplayText(item.A2UserID)</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
Next
End Code
</tbody>
```

But `item.A2UserID` not show value.

[image]

Comment: `Html.DisplayText` is not appropriate there.  If what you want is to display the value of `item.A2UserID` then just put `item.A2UserID` there rather than passing it to `DisplayText`.

Comment: Can you demo code show value ? tks

Comment: Read what I said and do it.